# Xamarin Forms - How we to connect with MI-Band using ble

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin forms i want to connect with MI-Band using BLE

Comment: Are you talking about Xiaomi's MI Band?

Comment: You can refer to this sample to have a try with connecting BLE Device. https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/mobile/BluetoothLEExplorer/ Then can refer to this java sample to read data from MI-Band. https://github.com/Jiesean/MiBandReader

Comment: Yes SushiHangover I am talking about MI Band

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang I am able to connect with MI Band but i am not able to get data of heart beat and other data